# Web and mobile, where to store token/cookies

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt

I'm developing a program which consists of a back-end server, a mobile application, and a web application. I have added JWT token to my mobile application and I'm storing in async storage. However, I cannot find an appropriate way to do in web server.

I have created a middleware file for creating and checking token's validity. In my API route's I'm doing the following

```
router.post('/:url', middleware.checkToken, (req, res, next)=>
{
  ...
}
```

So, every time I call this API, middleware file checks for the token. In my mobile application, I'm storing the token in the async storage and pass it to the web server.

However, in the browser side, I want to store the token inside a cookie rather than storing in local storage. How can I do this without changing my code?

This is mobile login API.

```
router.post('/login', (req,res,next) => {

let username = req.body.username;
let password = req.body.password;

User.findOne({'username' : username})
.exec()
.then(doc =>{
    if(doc.validPassword(password))
    {
        let token = jwt.sign({
            id: doc.id, 
            email: doc.email,
        },
            config.secret,
            { expiresIn: '24h' // expires in 24 hours
            }
        );
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: 'Authentication successful!',
            token: token
        });
    }
    else{
        // invalid credentials
        res.send(403).json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Incorrect username or password'
        });
    }
})
})
```

I don't want a separate file for web login. I just want to use the same code, without copying to another file.

**Should I write another different code for both mobile and web but one send a cookie, other sends plain token? Is there any way to achieve this with simple solution?**

In short:

Mobile users send credentials to the mobile login page and they receive token.
Web users send credentials to the web page and they receive a cookie (a token resides inside the cookie). I don't want to have separate code for login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily add a new cookie in the front-end with `document.cookie = ...` ([MDN document cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie))

In your middleware, you just have to parse for cookie instead of some `Bearer` token or whatever.

Comment: But, isn't that be less secure?

Comment: Where doe's the lack of security come from? In both cases you'll use a JWT as the `Bearer ` Token for validation. Just the way you make it accessable for you and the browser differs. Either you safe it within a cookie or in local or sessionStorage.

Comment: By the way: I would recommend using a cookie. The localStorage is accessable in all of your browser windows - and this could be a lack of security not the use of a cookie.

Comment: I thought it is less secure because I'm doing it in the client, not in the server.

Comment: As i understood you want to use a JSON webtoken for authentication? In this case you have to store it anywhere on the clientside, so the browser can send it within every request to your server - you have two options: a cookie or the localstorage.

Comment: @DavidJoos so should there be two separate endpoints for browser and mobile? Web stores jwt in cookie and mobile sends jwt in body

Comment: There are several ways to determine which platform did the request in the end. I think its up to you how to solve it ;)